flutter when build release apk to try it on Real device Closes before starting a video and i use in my project youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.2 package
That is my play yotube screen . Please help me solve the problem. When I press the video button to go to this screen, the application closes without any intervention .
For your information, everything works normally while running on the emulator in debug mode the problem just in release mode .
Code
late YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  late String url = widget.url;
  late YoutubePlayer youtubePlayer;
  late String id;
  late bool isPlaying, isMute;
  late String author;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    isMute = false;
    id = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(url)!;
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: id,
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(autoPlay: false),
    );
    youtubePlayer = YoutubePlayer(
      controller: _controller,
    );
    isPlaying = _controller.value.isPlaying;
    author = _controller.metadata.author;

  
  }

  Widget setAuthor() {
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (_controller.metadata.author != null) {
      setState(() {
        author = _controller.metadata.author;
      });
      return Text(
        author,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.pink,
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return setAuthor();
    }
  }


SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      _backAction(),
                     
                      Positioned(
                        top: 130,
                        left: 3,
                        right: 3,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 2 / 3.0,
                          child: _Player(),
                        ),
                      ),
                     
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );



 Widget _Player() {
    return YoutubePlayerBuilder(
      player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
              progressIndicatorColor: dustyRose,
           ),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget player) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              player,
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
             
              Text(
                widget.title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: textColorBlue,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 30),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Text(
                widget.artist,
                style: const TextStyle(color: textColorBlack, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                widget.duration,
                style: const TextStyle(color: textColorBlack),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
              author == null
                  ? setAuthor()
                  : Text(
                      _controller.metadata.author,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.pink,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 25),
                    ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              buttonRowBuilder(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  buttonRowBuilder() {
    double size = 35;
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (_controller.value.position <= const Duration(seconds: 30)) {
              _controller.seekTo(const Duration(seconds: 0));
            } else {
              var p = _controller.value.position - const Duration(seconds: 30);
              _controller.seekTo(p);
            }
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.replay_30, color: textColorBlue),
          iconSize: size,
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
              _controller.pause();
            } else {
              _controller.play();
            }
            setState(() {
              isPlaying = !isPlaying;
            });
          },
          icon: isPlaying
              ? const Icon(Icons.pause, color: textColorBlue)
              : const Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: textColorBlue),
          iconSize: size,
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            var newPostion =
                _controller.value.position + const Duration(seconds: 30);
            _controller.seekTo(newPostion);
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.forward_30, color: textColorBlue),
          iconSize: size,
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (isMute) {
              _controller.unMute();
            } else {
              _controller.mute();
            }
            setState(() {
              isMute = !isMute;
            });
          },
          icon: isMute
              ? const Icon(Icons.volume_off, color: textColorBlue)
              : const Icon(Icons.volume_up, color: textColorBlue),
          iconSize: size,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

builde.gradle
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.youtube_player"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }



 buildTypes {
        release {
        //    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }

I add these permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

I am using flutter version 3.0.1

check if there is any error message on debug console while playing the video.

Thank you for your answer
but everything works normally while running on the emulator in debug mode the problem just in release mode by Real device

@faredanageeb have you solved the issue ?

The issue might be related to the ProGuard rules configuration in your Android project when building in release mode.
When you build your Flutter app in release mode, ProGuard is enabled by default to optimize and obfuscate the code. Sometimes, ProGuard may obfuscate classes or methods that are used by external libraries, causing runtime issues such as crashing or unexpected behavior.
To fix this issue, you need to add specific ProGuard rules to ensure that the classes and methods used by the flutter_youtube_player plugin are not obfuscated by ProGuard.

Open the android/app/proguard-rules.pro file in your Flutter project

Add the following ProGuard rules to keep the classes and methods used by the flutter_youtube_player plugin:
#Keep the classes and methods used by flutter_youtube_player
-keep class com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.** { ; }
-keep interface com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.* { *; }




Thank you for your answer i solve the problem by add this line in AndroidManifest.xml                          and i run test on release mode by Real device  and everything works normally

okay good @faredanageeb

I solved the problem by add this line in AndroidManifest.xml
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your api key"/>

and i run test on release mode by Real device and everything works normally

